# propriedade Prompt nao esta funcionando

Tags: rails4, erb

```
<div class="field col-xs-3">
          <%= f.label :modelo_id %>
          <%= f.select :modelo_id, 
            options_for_select(
              @modelos.collect { |modelo|
              [modelo.nome.titleize, modelo.id] }, @carro.submodelo.modelo.id), {}, { id: 'modelos_select', class: 'form-control'  }, prompt: 'Selecionar disciplina' %>
        </div>
```

Alguem saberia me dizer porque o prompt nao esta funcionando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o `prompt` dentro do `hash` do `html_options`, tente da seguinte forma:

```html
<div class="field col-xs-3">
          <%= f.label :modelo_id %>
          <%= f.select :modelo_id, 
            options_for_select(
              @modelos.collect { |modelo|
              [modelo.nome.titleize, modelo.id] }, @carro.submodelo.modelo.id), {}, 
              { id: 'modelos_select', class: 'form-control'  , prompt: 'Selecionar disciplina' } %>
 </div>
```